# Android dependency graph

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, dependency-graph

I have huge android project with many modules and library dependencies.
It was nice to show something like dependency graph in nice and clear form.
[Something like this](http://www.tarind.com/depgraph_small.jpg)

I find some plugin for eclipse. But it´s not working properly.

Is there any online tool, application or plugin for android project or android studio?

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this [APK Dependency graph](https://github.com/alexzaitsev/apk-dependency-graph). It will give visual representation of dependencies that your app has.